# Redux toolkit thunk action generic error handler

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I'm enjoying redux-toolkit, but I'm wondering if there is a way to add a generic error handler for any rejected thunk? Just like the browser has the [unhandledrejection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event) event you can listen to, I'd like to report any rejected promises to my error tracker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want to run a side effect (sending a message to the server) every time a thunk is rejected.  I would suggest looking at [our new "listener middleware" for Redux Toolkit](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/discussions/1648?), which specifically lets you trigger additional logic when certain actions are dispatched.

The listener middleware is currently a separate `@rtk-incubator/action-listener-middleware` package as we've been iterating on its API, but as of today the API is stable and we plan to officially release it as part of RTK 1.8 shortly.  You can use it in that package today, and switch to importing it from RTK as soon as that release comes out.

Here's what it might look like:

```js
// app/listenerMiddleware.js
import { isRejected } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { createListenerMiddleware } from '@rtk-incubator/action-listener-middleware';

const listenerMiddleware = createListenerMiddleware()

listenerMiddleware.startListening({
  matcher: isRejected,
  effect: async (action, listenerApi) => {
    // send a message to the server here containing info from the action
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an error state slice hold the global error and use [isRejected](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/matching-utilities#isrejected) matching function to check whether an action is a 'rejected' action creator from the `createAsyncThunk` promise lifecycle.

E.g.

```
import { configureStore, createAsyncThunk, createSlice, isRejected, isRejectedWithValue } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const thunkA = createAsyncThunk('a', async (_, thunkAPI) => {
  return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue('error a');
});

const thunkB = createAsyncThunk('b', async (_, thunkAPI) => {
  return Promise.reject('error b');
});

const thunkC = createAsyncThunk('c', async (_, thunkAPI) => {
  return { name: 'c' };
});

const thunkASlice = createSlice({
  name: 'thunkA',
  initialState: { name: '' },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(thunkA.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.name = (action.payload as any).name;
    });
  },
});

const thunkBSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'thunkB',
  initialState: { name: '' },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(thunkA.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.name = (action.payload as any).name;
    });
  },
});

const thunkCSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'thunkC',
  initialState: { name: '' },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(thunkA.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.name = (action.payload as any).name;
    });
  },
});

const errorSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'error',
  initialState: {
    message: '',
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(isRejected, (state, action) => {
      // global error handle reducer
      state.message = 'some thunk rejected';
    });
  },
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    error: errorSlice.reducer,
    a: thunkASlice.reducer,
    b: thunkBSlice.reducer,
    c: thunkCSlice.reducer,
  },
});

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log('state:', store.getState());
});

// store.dispatch(thunkA());
store.dispatch(thunkB());
store.dispatch(thunkC());
```

Final state output:

```sh
state: {
  error: { message: 'some thunk rejected' },
  a: { name: '' },
  b: { name: '' },
  c: { name: '' }
}
```

`thunkA` and `thunkB` are 'rejected' actions, you can handle the rejected action in the `errorSlice` reducer centralized.

Comment: This is a good answer, with one caveat: it saves the results in state, whereas it sounds like the user wants to trigger side effects instead.